# RejectedExecutionException on submit worker

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, submit

I start get problems with a webservice deployed in weblogic 10.3.4. In this webservice, I created a new Callable class, to process commands:

```
public class CommandById implements Callable<DataBean> {
   private String docId = null;
   private String folder = null;

   public CommandById(final String docId, final String folder) {
      this.docId = docId;
      this.folder = folder;
   }

   @Override
   public DataBean call() throws Exception {
      // Do something with docId and folder
   }
}
```

so, I use this class in another class, in this way:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NTHREADS);
Callable<DataBean> worker = new CommandById(docId,folder);
Future<DataBean> submit = executor.submit(worker);
DataBean doc = null;
try {
   doc = submit.get();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
   executor.shutdown();
}
```

The first use, process command successfully. But, when I call again, I start gettting java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException, pointed to the line when I wrote `executor.submit(worker)`.

The stacktrace:

```
Error: [ServletContext@1747534847[app:BancoChile-Url module:reports path:/reports spec-version:2.5]] Servlet failed with Exception
cl.xxx.yyy.Exception: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException
        at cl.xxx.yyy.servlet.Worker.doGet(Unknown Source)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3717)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1774)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:768)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:656)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:92)
        at cl.xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa.getDocument(aaa.java:252)
        at cl.xxx.yyy.bbb.processId(bbb.java:941)
        at cl.xxx.yyy.zzz.getResultsById(zzz.java:692)
        at cl.xxx.yyy.zzz.getResults(zzz.java:384)
        ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is missing.
You can get `RejectedExecutionException` in case you have exceeded the number of maximum threads allowed (how much is `NTHREADS`)? OR in case the threadpool is in shutdown process.
Do you always use the same threadpool? if so, the `executor.shutdown()` in your finally block can explain this.

Comment: Thanks! the `executor.shutdown()` was the problem. I remove the finally block and all is work fine.